# Pm2 and nginx not communicating failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, pm2

Hello I am experiecing the error code Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and have found the error code below in nginx error.log. I am using pm2 and nginx. I have tried to restart both pm2 and nginx but it didnt fix anything. Pm2 status is telling me everything is working fine and pm2 logs are saying the server is running. So my best guess is going of the code below. How do I fix it?

```
2022/05/18 13:19:26 [crit] 19004#19004: *1003 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while keepalive, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I also get this error code now from pm2 logs:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3005
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/ubuntu/apps/bachelor-app/Server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/apps/bachelor-app/Server/Server.js:239:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3005
}
```

I can however only see one of them running with pm2 status